# ThrowingException Causing UnitTest Break?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit

I have a situation that at some case the actual function throwing an exception and i written unit test for it but unfortunately the unit test is failed.

**Sample Code**:

```
// 'CheckNumber()' function is Present in 'Number' class.

public int CheckNumber(int Number)
{
    if (Number < 0 || Number > MaxNumber) // MaxNumber = 300
       throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();

    //..     
}
```

**Unit Test**:

I am using *NUnit Framework*.

```
// When The Number is Less than Zero Or Greater than Maximun Number

[Test]
public void CheckNumberTest()
{
   Number number = new Number();
   int returnedValue = number.CheckNumber(-1);

   // Assertion.
   Assert.That(returnedValue , Throws.ArgumentOutOfRangeException);
}
```

This Test is failing when i run test. This test is actually throwing the exception and TestMethod is going to break? So How to fix it?

Comment: Try use `Assert.Throws<ArgumentOutOfRangeException>(() => your function)`

Comment: I tried this: but Test is still failing! `Assert.Throws<ArgumentOutOfRangeException>(() => CheckNumberTest)` @johnny

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that your method doesn't return any value but instead throws exception.

```
int returnedValue = number.CheckNumber(-1); //throws ArgumentOutOfRangeException
```

The test code executes as every other peace of code and it will bubble exception up before someone catch it. In your case it was caught by test executor because you do not have any try/catch block here.

The proper way to write your test is to use `Assert.Throws<TException>`.

```
[Test]
public void CheckNumberTest()
{
    //Arrange
   Number number = new Number();

   //Act
   var throws = new TestDelegate(() => number.CheckNumber(-1));

   //Assert.
   Assert.Throws<ArgumentOutOfRangeException>(throws);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please check documentation  [here](http://nunit.org/nunitv2/docs/2.6/exceptionAsserts.html)!

and you will of course need to understand variances between exceptions in the same link 
this should help you thorough

```
// Require an ApplicationException - derived types fail!
Assert.Throws( typeof(ApplicationException), code );
Assert.Throws<ApplicationException>()( code );

// Allow both ApplicationException and any derived type
Assert.Throws( Is.InstanceOf( typeof(ApplicationException), code );
Assert.Throws( Is.InstanceOf<ApplicationException>(), code );

// Allow both ApplicationException and any derived type
Assert.Catch<ApplicationException>( code );

// Allow any kind of exception
Assert.Catch( code )
```